# Long term beacon ranging causes Bluetooth failure

Tags: bluetooth

We have an Android app that does beacon scanning using altbeacon  This can be with the app in the foreground or background.  After some random time interval (usually hours, but not always) of beacon ranging the Bluetooth will stop working.  At that point no Bluetooth devices, beacons or otherwise, can be detected.  It requires Bluetooth to be turned off and back on before BT works and beacons are detected again.

Other beacon scanner apps from the store also fail to detect any beacons when this issue occurs.

We added BluetoothMedic from altbeacon, but it never detects a problem.  The issue seems to occur on Moto g6 (OS 8) and Moto g7 (OS 9) phones.  Have not seen the issue on a Google Pixel 3 (OS 10) or Samsung S8 (OS 8).

So, the question is, is there a way to detect Bluetooth being on, but failing to detect devices?  If we can do that, we can trigger a Bluetooth power cycle to correct the issue.  Better yet, is there something that can be done to prevent the problem in the first place?  Looking online this type of failure seems to be not uncommon with the solution being a Bluetooth power cycle.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have any log that may indicate what is going wrong? For example the Bluetooth daemon may crash.

Comment: None of our logs are showing any crashes, unfortunately.  Then we'd at least know something went wrong.  Thanks.